# Is it possible to pass user ID and password through Process.Start() in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, process.start

I am working on WPF application. I want to open a external browser instead of in-built browser and I want to pass the user login credential in it in such the way that it should not be browser specific. Right now I am using Prosses.Start("URL") to open the external Browser?

Comment: this depends on the `commandline args` that browser is supporting. You truely can pass it to any application but the question is if the other application can handle it...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass HTTP Basic Authentication credentials to a website that you open, you may do it directly via URL like this

> https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.whatever.com

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code, it might correspond to your demand:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("URL");

startInfo.UserName = "UN";
startInfo.Password = "pass";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways for doing this, and the website you are trying to login should support one  these:

1. HTTP Basic Authentication: that our friend "3615" mentioned..
2. Sending username and password through GET request:

http://whatever.com/auth.php?username=[USERNAME]&password=[PASSWORD]